# Strange extended ascii / non printing characters output by php (byte order mark?)

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii

I have inherited a mamoth php site. This site works fine on the live server, however we have a sandbox / QA server on which to make changes, and on this server (Which almost certainaly has different PHP settings etc) I am seeing some strange characters being output before the content I desire.

They've caused numerous issues and to date I have "fixed" them by making use of `ob_start()` and `ob_clean_end()` at the start of a php script, and then just before I output content respectively.

However I've now hit this issue one time too many for me to be comfortable continuing.  The site changes go live next week, and there's a chance the sandbox / QA server will just become the live server.  If that happens I'd like to be sure this issue will not randomly popup again.

Does anyone know why the characters with ASCII codes (as reported by `ord()`)
239, 187 and 191.

They appear to be a byte order mark for UTF-8, but I have no idea why they are there or how to prevent them being there...

Comment: Yes, those are the ascii values of the UTF-8 BOM, commonly added by using the wrong editor. `phptags -b --whitespace *.php` fixes those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UTF8 byte order mark is placed by some editors in UTF8 encoded files. They aren't required, so the best way to solve your problem would be to remove all BOM's from the files.

If you have a lot of files, it might be best to use a script to automate it. You can find examples of such scripts on google, like [this one](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.fi/2010/09/shell-script-to-find-and-remove-bom.html)

Comment: I ended up using the File BOM Detector (Freeware) found here http://www.bryntyounce.com/filebomdetector.htm as I was on a Windows server /sigh.  Worked perfectly, quickly and easily.